# How to use unique_together method in django views

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

```
class Model1(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
     password = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)

class Model2(models.Model):
     name = models.ForeignKey(Model1, null=True)
     unique_str = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
     class Meta:
           unique_together = (('name', 'unique_str'),)
```

I've already filled 3 sample username-password in Model1 through django-admin page

In my views I'm getting this list as

```
userlist = Model1.objects.all()
#print userlist[0].username, userlist[0].password

for user in userlist:
     #here I want to get or create model2 object by uniqueness defined in meta class.
     #I mean unique_str can belong to multiple user so I'm making name and str together as a unique key but I dont know how to use it here with get_or_create method.
     #right now (without using unique_together) I'm doing this (but I dont know if this by default include unique_together functionality )
     a,b = Model2.objects.get_or_create(unique_str='f3h6y67')
     a.name = user
     a.city = "acity"
     a.save()
```

Comment: Hello so you are extending your Model class into Model1 and Model2. You have already created the a,b objects for model2. What is the problem you are facing over here?

Comment: This question really doesn't make sense. `unique_together` is not a method, it's a constraint. You don't call it, or do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're saying is that your logical key is a combination of `name` and `unique_together`, and that you what to use that as the basis for calls to `get_or_create()`.

First, understand the `unique_together` creates a database constraint. There's no way to *use* it, and Django doesn't do anything special with this information.

Also, at this time Django cannot use composite natural primary keys, so your models by default will have an auto-incrementing integer primary key. But you can still use `name` and `unique_str` as a key.

Looking at your code, it seems you want to do this:

```
a, _ = Model2.objects.get_or_create(unique_str='f3h6y67', 
                                    name=user.username)
a.city = 'acity'
a.save()
```

On Django 1.7 you can use `update_or_create()`:

```
a, _ = Model2.objects.update_or_create(unique_str='f3h6y67', 
                                       name=user.username,
                                       defaults={'city': 'acity'})
```

In either case, the key point is that the keyword arguments to `_or_create` are used for looking up the object, and `defaults` is used to provide additional data in the case of a create or update. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

In sum, to "use" the `unique_together` constraint you simply use the two fields together whenever you want to uniquely specify an instance.